# Supertest request with CSRF fails

Tags: express, csrf, supertest, ava

I have an **Express** 4 application that makes user of **csurf** for CSRF protection on API routes. The application is working perfectly and CSRF protection is indeed working where requests without the `csrf-token` header will give the appropriate error.

I make use of **Ava** for testing with **supertest** for testing routes. The following test fails when CSRF checking is enabled but passes if I remove the middleware:

```
test('booking api no auth', async t => {
  t.plan(4)

  const server = await request(makeServer(t.context.config, t.context.connection))

  const csrf = await server
    .get('/')
    .then(res => new JSDOM(res.text))
    .then(dom => dom.window.document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf_token"]'))
    .then(csrfMeta => csrfMeta.getAttribute('content'))

  const GET = await server
    .get('/v2/Booking')
    .set('csrf-token', csrf)

  const POST = await server
    .post('/v2/Booking')
    .set('csrf-token', csrf)
    .send({
      name: 'Test',
      description: 'Test',
      category: 'diving',
      minimumPax: 1,
      maximumPax: 2,
      priceAdult: 1,
      priceChild: 1
    })

  const res = { GET, POST }

  t.is(res.GET.status, 403)
  t.deepEqual(res.GET.body, text['403'])
  t.is(res.POST.status, 201)
  t.truthy(res.POST.body._id)
})
```

I have verified that the header is indeed set in the request. Any ideas or suggestions for alternative libraries that works is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've previously also had errors with `supertest` and logging in, still unresolved, but using `supertest-session` seems to have fixed this for me. Fix was to replace:

```
import request from 'supertest'
```

with

```
import request from 'supertest-session'
```

and everything magically works.