# How can I test the Sails.js v1.0 login controller with CSRF security enabled (using mocha, supertest)?

Tags: testing, sails.js, mocha.js, csrf, supertest

I have an almost-new Sails.js 1.0.2 app and I'm able to log in with both a browser and with Postman.  However, I can't seem to make the same process work in my test runner.

The test below should result in a successful login, where a cookie is returned with a new session ID. If I change the security configuration to disable [CSRF protection](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/security/csrf), it runs perfectly. But with security enabled, the request is forbidden (403). The only substantial difference between what I'm sending in Postman seems to be that mocha runs the app on a different port (Postman sends to `localhost:1337`, express' res variable says `PUT /api/v1/entrance/login HTTP/1.1 Host: 127.0.0.1:56002`

Anyone see something I'm missing?

Here's the test file:

```
/**
 * /test/integration/controllers/entrance/login.test.js
 */

'use strict';

const supertest = require('supertest');  // also tried supertest-session

describe('Entrance controllers', () => {

  describe('/api/v1/entrance/login', () => {

    before(() => {
      return supertest(sails.hooks.http.app)
      .get('/login')
      .then(res => {
        const reTokenCapture = /_csrf:\s*unescape\('([^']+)'\)/;
        const found = reTokenCapture.exec(res.text);
        this._csrf = sails.config.security.csrf ? found[1] : '';
        this.url = '/api/v1/entrance/login';
      });
    });

    it('should return a session cookie in response headers', () => {
      return supertest(sails.hooks.http.app)
      .put(this.url)
      .set('x-csrf-token', this._csrf)
      .send({
        emailAddress: 'admin@example.com',
        password: 'abc123',
        // _csrf: this._csrf,  // I tried this too; no luck
      })
      .expect(200)  // if sails.config.security.csrf is enabled, status is 403
      .then(res => {
        // console.log('res:', res);  // this shows the correct header
        res.headers['set-cookie'].should.be.an('array');
        const hasSid = res.headers['set-cookie'].map(cookie => {
          const reSid = /^sails\.sid=[^;]+;\sPath=\/;(?:\sExpires=[^;]+GMT;)?\sHttpOnly$/;
          return reSid.test(cookie);
        });
        hasSid.should.include.members([true]);
      });
    });

  });

});
```

I'm running node v8.11.3, sails v1.0.2, mocha v5.2.0, supertest v3.1.0, chai v4.1.2

FYI, here's the request made by Postman that worked fine (CSRF token was copied by hand by a previous Postman request to `GET /login`):

```
PUT /api/v1/entrance/login HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:1337
x-csrf-token: mjWXQTa2-RFEHu78Tr-JGJwhWeryKGRJI4S8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: e3d920fe-6178-4642-80e4-8005b477fd98

{"emailAddress": "admin@example.com", "password":"abc123"}
```

Comment: I hoped that this solution would help, but no such luck: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44828161/1811952

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got it! I thought I was meant to get the session ID from the `set-cookie` header after logging in. Instead, I'm meant to capture both the CSRF token and session ID while still logged out, then submit email & password, then use the token and ID in subsequent requests. I missed this detail in Postman because I failed to notice the cookie that was persisting between requests.

Here's the fixed test file **(now works with CSRF protections enabled)**:

```
/**
 * /test/integration/controllers/entrance/login.test.js
 */

'use strict';

const supertest = require('supertest');  // also tried

describe('Entrance controllers', () => {

  describe('/api/v1/entrance/login', () => {

    before(() => {
      this._url = '/api/v1/entrance/login';

      return supertest(sails.hooks.http.app).get('/login')
      .then(getRes => {
        const reTokenCapture = /_csrf:\s*unescape\('([^']+)'\)/;
        const foundToken = reTokenCapture.exec(getRes.text);
        this._csrf = sails.config.security.csrf ? foundToken[1] : '';
        this._cookie = getRes.headers['set-cookie'].join('; ');
      });

    });

    it('should accept the session ID & CSRF token procured by GET /login', () => {
      return supertest(sails.hooks.http.app)
      .put(this._url)
      .set('Cookie', this._cookie)
      .set('X-CSRF-Token', this._csrf)
      .send({
        emailAddress: 'admin@example.com',
        password: 'abc123',
      })
      .expect(200);
    });

    it('should reject requests without a CSRF token', () => {
      return supertest(sails.hooks.http.app)
      .put(this._url)
      .set('Cookie', this._cookie)
      .expect(403);
    });

    it('should reject requests without a session cookie', () => {
      return supertest(sails.hooks.http.app)
      .put(this._url)
      .set('Cookie', '')
      .set('x-csrf-token', this._csrf)
      .expect(403);
    });

    it('should reject requests with invalid tokens', () => {
      return supertest(sails.hooks.http.app)
      .put(this._url)
      .set('Cookie', 'sails.sid=foo; Path=/; HttpOnly')
      .set('X-CSRF-Token', 'foo')
      .send({
        emailAddress: 'admin@example.com',
        password: 'abc123',
      })
      .expect(403);
    });

    it('should reject requests with invalid credentionals', () => {
      return supertest(sails.hooks.http.app)
      .put(this._url)
      .set('Cookie', this._cookie)
      .set('X-CSRF-Token', this._csrf)
      .send({
        emailAddress: 'user@example.com',
        password: 'password'
      })
      .expect(401);
    });

    it('should reject get requests', () => {
      return supertest(sails.hooks.http.app)
      .get(this._url)
      .set('Cookie', this._cookie)
      .set('X-CSRF-Token', this._csrf)
      .send({
        emailAddress: 'admin@example.com',
        password: 'abc123',
      })
      .expect(404);
    });

    it('should reject post requests', () => {
      return supertest(sails.hooks.http.app)
      .post(this._url)
      .set('Cookie', this._cookie)
      .set('X-CSRF-Token', this._csrf)
      .send({
        emailAddress: 'admin@example.com',
        password: 'abc123',
      })
      .expect(404);
    });

  });

});
```

Comment: Ohhh I finally understood what he's doing here - https://github.com/mikermcneil/ration/blob/6d78368beff43f4b4ded25b01f8917239b6d481b/test/private/before.js#L56 - he is trying to get the CSRF in. You got it from the login page, he gets it by exposing `/.temporary/csrf/token/for/tests`!

Comment: Yeah, I think the route you use to get those credentials doesn't matter, so long as you get them both from the same API call (not two separate calls).

Comment: Seriously thank you for doing it the HTML extraction way, it totally was what made it click. It made this Sails doc click - https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/security/csrf